# ¿Por qué me está saliendo el siguiente error en angular al consumir un json?

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var contactsServices = angular.module('miClaroController', []);

appController.controller("ConsumerCuentaController",['$scope','$http', 'servicioMiClaro',function($scope,$http,servicioMiClaro){

    servicioMiClaro.consumerCuenta('hola').then(function(d) {
        $scope.listarConsumer = d;
    });

    servicioMiClaro.obtenerDirecciones('hola').then(function(data) {
        $scope.listadoProductoServicios = data;
    });
]);

var appServices = angular.module('miClaroServices',[]);  

appServices.factory('servicioMiClaro', function($http) {
    var promise;
    var myService = {
        consumerCuenta: function(valor) {
            if ( !promise ) {
                 promise = $http.get('http://172.19.74.xx:8909/ProyectoResulFull/service/consumerCuenta/p').then(function (response) {

                     console.log(valor);
                     return response.data;
                 });
           }
           // Return the promise to the controller
           return promise;
       };
       obtenerDirecciones: function(valor) {
           if ( !promise ) {        
               promise = $http.get('http://172.19.74.xx:8909/ProductoServiciosResulFull/service/obtenerDirecciones/p').then(function (response) {
                    console.log(valor);       
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise;
        }
    };  
    return myService;
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes un `;` entre `consumerCuenta` y `obtenerDirecciones`. Eso te debe estar causando el error. En javascript el separador de llaves de los objetos es una `,`. En lugar de `{consumerCuenta: ...; obtenerDirecciones: ...}` debe ser `{consumerCuenta: ..., obtenerDirecciones: ...}`

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque se trata de un simple error tipográfico